# NLog File is not creating After publishing the WEBAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nlog

I have Used NLog for logging and its working on local but when i published it then its not creating the log file while requesting the API. i have also set the

```
Copy to output directory  = Copy always
```

Here is NLog.config File

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log" >


  <!-- optional, add some variabeles
  https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#variables
  -->
  <variable name="myvar" value="myvalue"/>

  <!-- 
  See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file 
  for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->
  <targets>

    <!-- 
    add your targets here 
    See https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Targets for possible targets.
    See https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Layout-Renderers for the possible layout renderers.
    -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="DebugFile" fileName="${basedir}/logs/Debug_${shortdate}.log" layout="${longdate} ${threadid} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}"/>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ErrorFile" fileName="${basedir}/logs/Error_${shortdate}.log" layout="${longdate} ${threadid} ${uppercase:${level}}  ${message} ${newline} ${exception:format=tostring} ${newline}"/>
    <!--
    Writing events to the a file with the date in the filename. 
    <target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
    -->
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!-- add your logging rules here -->

    <!--
    Write all events with minimal level of Debug (So Debug, Info, Warn, Error and Fatal, but not Trace)  to "f"
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="f" />
    -->
    <logger name="*" levels="Debug,Info,Warn" writeTo="DebugFile" />

    <logger name="*" level="Error" writeTo="ErrorFile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Please tell me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Does the worker process have permission to write to the log file?

Comment: I am not sure about it. okay i will check and reply.

Comment: For debugging purposes you can enable throwExceptions in your config